# Ajax url action possible without another url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to integrate ajax for not getting the page refreshed when i save something and only get a confirmation message. The problem is that I get the confirmation message but data is not inserted in the database.

page.inc

```
public function addtofavorites() {
    $q = "select * from carads where STATUS='1' and DEL='0' and ADID=".$_REQUEST['carID'];
    $result = $this->QueryResult($q);
    if($result[0]->TITLE!='-1' || $result[0]->TITLE!='') {
      $title = $result[0]->TITLE;
    } else {
      $title = 'No Title';
    }
    if($result[0]->IMAGE1!='-1' || $result[0]->IMAGE1!='') {
      $image = $result[0]->IMAGE1;
    } else {
      $image = 'uploads/noimg.jpg';
    } 
   include("inc/membersite_config.php");
   $email = $fgmembersite->UserEmail();
   $carlink = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $carlink = explode('_', $carlink);
   $carlink = $carlink[1];
   $insertarray = array(
      'email' => $email,
          'favoritecarlink' => $carlink,
          'favoritecartitle' => $title,
      'favoritecarimg' => $image);
   $q2 = "select * from favoritecar WHERE email='$email'";
   $resultfav = $this->QueryResult($q2);
   foreach ($resultfav as $resultfavs) {
   $carlinkdbs[] = $resultfavs->favoritecarlink;
   }
   if (!empty($carlinkdbs)) {
 if (in_array($carlink, $carlinkdbs)) {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){ $("#addtofavs").click(function(){ $("#hidemes").text("Car had been already added to your favorite cars");  });  $("#addtofav").blur(function(){ $("#hidemes").text(""); }); });</script>';
   echo '<input type="submit" name="addtofav" onclick="displaymessage()" id="addtofavs" class="addtofav" value="">';
     } else {
   if (isset($_POST["addtofav"])) {
         $this->InsertValues($insertarray, 'favoritecar');
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Car had been added to favorites");</script>';
     }
         echo '<script>$(function () { $("form").on("submit", function (e) { $.ajax({type: "post", url: "", data: $("form").serialize(), success: function () { alert("form was submitted"); } }); e.preventDefault(); }); });</script>';
     echo '<form>';
         echo '<input type="submit" name="addtofav" onclick="displaymessage()" id="addtofavs" class="addtofav" value="">';
         echo '</form>';
     } 
   } else {
   if (isset($_POST["addtofav"])) {
         $this->InsertValues($insertarray, 'favoritecar');
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Car had been added to favorites");</script>';
   }
     echo '<form>';
         echo '<input type="submit" name="addtofav" onclick="displaymessage()" id="addtofavs" class="addtofav" value="">';
         echo '</form>';
   }
}
```

I tried with

```
$(function () { 
  $("form").on("submit", function (e) { 
  $.ajax({type: "post", url: "", data: $("form").serialize(), success: function(){ alert("form was submitted"); } }); e.preventDefault(); }); });
```

`$this->InsertValues($insertarray, 'favoritecar');` // this is how the data is inserted in the database. `$insertarray` is the array where data is being hold and `favoritecar` is the table where it goes. I want to say that in the old fashion method with `<form action="" method="post">` works fine it's inserting the data showing message and reloading.

Functions `QueryResult` and `InsertValues` are custom functions that look like this:
http://pastebin.com/8cpA9R4Q

I tried also adding to the url from the ajax url: "page.inc" - the actual page that the code sits on, but it did not echo any success messages.

Please help me I am a noob in ajax. This is my first attempt on implementing ajax. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: But what you expect `url: ""` to do?

Comment: @A.Wolff to do that `<form action="" method="post">` does

Comment: You should add e.preventDefault(); before $ajax...

Comment: This has nothing to do with FORM action. You need to set as option URL of ajax request the path to server side script you are targeting to add content to database

Comment: A. Wolff, oups, i miss-understood the concept. Will be a long week...

Comment: @MichałK. same behaviour, setted after or before

Comment: @A. Wolff sorry, I though tere is no preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, I'd like to know if your data are correctly retrieve in your php function addtofavorites() ? Can you show us your $_POST values ?
- For me the action is correctly stop after the form submitting.
- The url attribute can be empty ?
- This will not be an answer to your question but an advice and an another step. If you are making an AJAX request, don't put javascript in your PHP code. Ok, it's work but it's ugly. I suggest you to return a boolean to know if insertion was a success (or a 'code' like you want).

  ```
  $("form").on("submit", function (e) { 
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "",
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        // Check data response... if true insert was a success else an error occurred
      } 
    }); 
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  ```

Comment: I appreciate your response but it's a bit more complicated.Here is what i am trying, the function addtofavorites() is located in a class called `class WebUser extends CommanFunctions` in the file details-page.inc. I removed all form and if isset instances in the functions and right now i am trying to call the public function addtofavorites() when the submit button is clicked, but can't find exactly how to do that. I currently added the form to the front-end in details-page.php

Comment: Oh ! The problem is how you can call the function from your AJAX request ? You should find a way to pass the values in your url. **url : "?className=N2&functionName=addtofavorites"**. It's just a sample, I don't know your whole architecture.